# How to display all rows from MySQL GROUP and HAVING aggregation query?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, aggregate

I would like the following MySQL aggregation query in phpMyadmin to show all of the rows of the grouped column. I can make the aggregation, but I have not been able to show all of the rows of the aggregated column.

How would I modify this to show all of the rows for each star?

For example, from the screen below, I would need the query to show all three rows for the star "Amahumasi"

MySQL statement:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(STAR) AS NumRings
FROM 'TABLE 3'
GROUP BY STAR
HAVING COUNT(STAR) >2
ORDER BY PLANET ASC
```

[image: Aggregate counts highlighted at right side of image:]

Comment: 'TABLE 3' and \`TABLE 3\` are two different things. But either way, see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the best way, but I believe it works:

```
SELECT * FROM `Table 3` WHERE STAR IN (SELECT STAR FROM `Table 3` GROUP BY STAR HAVING COUNT(STAR) > 2) ORDER BY PLANET ASC
```

Comment: Hi thanks! This worked. I see now that you must do a second select to make this type of query work.